# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.method.then is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React to build a website. On one of the pages, users can see all users' profiles and select tags to filter them. In addition to the tags selected, I also keep the list of users displayed in the state of the component for another feature. Therefore, when the user clicks or un-clicks a tag, not only the list of tags (called "filters") but also the currently displayed users' profiles (called "currentprofilelist") will be changed. Below is my code to achieve this feature: "updateTasks" is called when the user clicks a tag, which calls "onlyFilters" to change the "filters" field in the state. Then "onlyFilters" returns the new filters, which is passed to filtersUpdateList to modify the "currentprofilelist" in the state. I got the error: **"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.onlyFilters(...).then is not a function"** and am wondering how I can fix it. I tried adding "return" before it and it still did not work. Thanks for your patience!

```
    const filters = [

    ......

    ]

    state = {
      ......
      filters: [],
      currentprofilelist: []
    }

   componentDidMount() {
      const { users } = this.props;
      this.setState({
        currentprofilelist: users
      })
    }

    ......

    onlyFilters = (e) => {
      if (e.target.className === "unselected-button") {
        const helper = this.state.filters;
        helper.push(e.target.id);
        this.setState({ filters : helper });
        e.target.className = "selected-button";
        return helper;
       }
        else {
          const newfilters = this.state.filters.filter(tag => tag !== e.target.id);
          this.setState({ filters : newfilters });
          e.target.className = "unselected-button";
          return newfilters;
        }
    }

    filtersUpdateList = (newfilters) => {
      const { users } = this.props;
      var newprofilelist = [];
      var i = 0;
      while (i < users.length) {
        if (newfilters.every(t => users[i].profile.areas_of_interest && users[i].profile.areas_of_interest.includes(t))) {
          newprofilelist.push(users[i].id);
        }
      }
      this.setState({currentprofilelist: newprofilelist});
    }

    updateFilters = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.onlyFilters(e)
      .then((newfilters) => {
        this.filtersUpdateList(newfilters);
      })
    }

    ......

   render() {

        const { auth, users, profile } = this.props;

        return (
         ......
          <Container fluid style={{ marginLeft:"70px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center",  zIndex: "-1"}}>

            <div className="filter-container">
            <li>Filter by interests!</li>
            <div className="form-inline">
              {filters.map(filter => {
                return (
                  <div className="unselected-button" id={filter} onClick={this.updateFilters}>
                    {filter}
                    </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
            </div>


           ......

          </Container>



        ......
        );
      }
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    users: state.firestore.ordered.users,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    profile: state.firebase.profile
  }
}

......
```

Comment: `.then` is a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) method. Its not available to just any function return. `onlyFilters` doesn't return a promise, so you can't use `.then`, its as simple as that.

Comment: Instead, you should read about [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) which is perfect for handling side-effects of state changes.

Comment: Another tip: `helper.push(e.target.id)` is mutating state. Change it to this: `const helper = [...this.state.filters, e.target.id]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onlyFilters method should be async function to use its result with promise, so try to declare it like:

```
onlyFilters = async () => {....}
```

or

```
async onlyFilters() {....}
```